# JavaScript setCustomValidity not working when setting on input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to `setCustomValidity()` on an `input`, but it is not showing. Any Ideas?

```js
function submitForm() {
  //$("#username")[0].setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address.');
  let username = document.getElementById("username");
  console.log(username);
  username.setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email address.');
  //alert('Please enter a valid email address.');
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="form-floating field">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$" maxlength="100" required id="username" name="username" class="text form-control" value="" placeholder="Email" />
    <label for="username">Email</label>
    <span class="autoComplete-img"><img src="assets/images/envelope-gray.svg" alt=""></span>
  </div>
  <div class="actions margin-1rem-top text-center">
    <input type="hidden" id="response" name="response" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" id="forgotPasswordBtn" name="forgotPasswordBtn" value="" />
    <button type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="submit butn butn-blue butn-md" onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem was that it was missing `username.reportValidity();` after the `setCustomValidity ` call.  - p.s. I am not sure why I get down votes for this question?

Comment: All questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. If JSFiddle ever goes out of business, your question should still be valuable to future visitors. Your initial question didn't contain any code whatsoever, so it was off-topic which likely attracted some downvotes. (The fact that you also have over 500 questions asked and thus "should know better" probably doesn't work in your favor either in regards to downvotes.)

Comment: Thanks  for the feedback, things I wan't aware of, but am now.

Comment: I removed the link to JSFiddle and inserted the code as a Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a click event on the submit button you can just "go with the flow" of the form submitting.

So, here I changed the submit button so that it only acts as a submit button. You already gave the input element the required attribute, so the form will only submit if it is valid. I made an event listener for `invalid` on the form. So, each time a input element is invalid on submission this callback function will be called. Notice the `useCapture` parameter on `addEventListener()` is set to `true`, this means that the `setCustomValidity()` will be called before the message is shown and the custom text will show up (notice the message text is in a data- attribute of the input element, so that the invalid callback can be used for any input element in the form with this attribute).

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Submitting...');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  if ('message' in e.target.dataset) {
    e.target.setCustomValidity(e.target.dataset.message);
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <div class="form-floating field">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off"
      pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$"
      maxlength="100" required id="username" name="username"
      class="text form-control" value="" placeholder="Email"
      data-message="Please enter a valid email address." />
    <label for="username">Email</label>
    <span class="autoComplete-img">
      <img src="assets/images/envelope-gray.svg" alt="">
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="actions margin-1rem-top text-center">
    <input type="hidden" name="response" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="forgotPasswordBtn" value="" />
    <button type="submit"
      class="submit butn butn-blue butn-md">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```